# Http get/post into dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get some data into dataflow, but the data is not located on cloud storage - it is an rss feed that I would normally check every x hours. Is there a way to do that directly using the SDK or do I have to get the files onto cloud storage some other way first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow doesn't provide a source for an RSS feed.

You could issue HTTP requests from a ParDo to fetch the data though. For example suppose the feed allowed you to fetch messages in some time range. Then you could create an input collection where each record represented a range of time (e.g. an hour). You could then write a ParDo which would fetch the messages in that time range and emit them.

If you are part of the streaming early access preview then 
one solution would be to write an App Engine App (or equivalent) which checked the RSS feed every X hours and then published the data using Google Cloud PubSub. You could then use [PubSubIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/PubsubIO) to read those events in Dataflow.

Comment: That makes sense... I was trying to create something like HttpIO.Read but I was coming up agains issues because on app engine we gave the fetch url api but when I am testing locally that api is not available. Do you know if there is a simple solution for that. I have looked at the google http client but cannot see an "obvious" way to use it :(

Comment: Thanks for the pub sub suggestion, worth a try for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question App Engine question. Can you please clarify what you were trying to access form DirectPipelineRunner? Are you trying to access an App Engine API or an app you have running on App Engine?

Comment: Sorry for confusing things, what I was trying to say that I am writing the locally for now, but I am hoping to run it from app engine eventually and was hoping that I could write the http get code once to work on both.

Comment: When running on the service, your ParDo's execute on a GCE VM not in App Engine. So your code won't have access to the App Engine runtime environment. So you probably don't want App Engine dependencies in your code.